# get calculated color of label within formatter callback

Tags: echarts

In Apache Echarts, the label formatter callback provides a "params" object as argument with helpful properties, including "color" which is the color of the item. In my case, in a pie chart, that's the color of the slice of the pie being labelled.

But the color of the label itself, if not overridden, is automatically calculated as either nearly black (on lighter colors) or nearly white (on darker colors). Using Richtext for a part of my label (amt and pct below), I would like to use a lighter shade of black/gray when the rest of the label is black, but a darker shade of white/gray if the rest of the label is white**.

So, I need to know what color ECharts is planning on making my label in order to override a piece of it to a different shade. Is it going to be white? Or black? But **there is no "labelColor" property in the params object. Is there a way to programmatically obtain this?** Or is there an algorithm that mimics how ECharts decides whether to make the label black or white that I can anticipate?

[image]

```
 formatter: (params) => {
    return params.name + "\n" + "{amt|" + params.value.formatter(params.value.value) + "} ({pct|" + params.percent + "}%)"
  },
  rich: {
    pct: {
      color: '#999' // needs to vary based on main label color
    },
    amt: {
      color: '#999' // needs to vary based on main label color
    }
  }
```

sample params value:

```
{
    "componentType": "series",
    "componentSubType": "pie",
    "componentIndex": 0,
    "seriesType": "pie",
    "seriesIndex": 0,
    "seriesId": "\u0000inner\u00000",
    "seriesName": "inner",
    "name": "OS Overhead",
    "dataIndex": 5,
    "data": {
        "name": "OS Overhead",
        "value": 5113741824
    },
    "value": {
        "name": "OS Overhead",
        "value": 5113741824
    },
    "color": "#3ba272",          // color of item/pie-slice, not of label
    "dimensionNames": [],
    "encode": {
        "value": [
            1
        ]
    },
    "$vars": [
        "seriesName",
        "name",
        "value",
        "percent"
    ],
    "percent": 0.01,
    "status": "normal"
}
```

Update: I did manage to accomplish the contrast requirement by calculating luminescence and setting both colors manually. But it would still be nice to work with ECharts auto-calculated label colors.

```
export const hex2RGB = (hex) => {
  const safeHex = hex.replace("#","")

  return {
    r: parseInt(safeHex.slice(0,2),16),
    g: parseInt(safeHex.slice(2,4),16),
    b: parseInt(safeHex.slice(4,6),16)
  }
}

export const getLuminescence = (hex) => {
  const color = hex2RGB(hex)
  return color.r * 0.299 + color.g * 0.587 + color.b * 0.114 // perceived brightness
}



//label option

  formatter: (params) => {
    const luminescence = getLuminescence(params.seriesName === "inner" ? params.color : "#ffffff")
    const styleTagSuffix = luminescence > 140 ? "Dark" : "Light"

    return "{name" + styleTagSuffix + "|" + params.name + "}\n" + "{value" + styleTagSuffix + "|" + params.value.formatter(params.value.value) + " (" + params.percent + "%)}"
  },
  rich: {
    valueDark: {
      align: "right",
      color: "#444444"
    },
    valueLight: {
      align: "right",
      color: "#bbbbbb"
    },
    nameDark: {
      align: "right",
      color: "#111111",
      fontWeight: "bold",
      fontSize: 16
    },
    nameLight: {
      align: "right",
      color: "#eeeeee",
      fontWeight: "bold",
      fontSize: 16
    },
```

Comment: The function that computes the default label colors wrt the background (i.e., PiePiece) is [`zRender/Path#getInsideFill`](https://github.com/ecomfe/zrender/blob/9197e0573daaedb2344a69acc83b4dd03d070615/src/graphic/Path.ts#L264). However, running a debug session with the full source code of echarts shows me that this function is called *after* all user `formatter` functions had run, so it seems that the actually computed label color is not available in the formatter. If an alternative approach comes to mind I'll post here.

Comment: Thanks for the extra effort. I think though that my workaround of computing the appropriate contrast myself works well enough for me. Enough to move ahead.